# Google apps script to hide columns by condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im actually using this script to hide rows that the last column contains "1"

```
    function HideComprasRows() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Compras');
  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, lastColumn, lastRow, 1);
  var data = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == 1) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

its working perfect for me , but I need the same for my columns that contains "1" in the first row

For example in this scenario:
[image]

columns F:K I need to hide (The "1" Value is coming from a specific formula from the column)

Any help with a script please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to hide the columns when the 1st row is `1`.
- In your case, the range you want to hide is from the column "B" to the last column.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I believe you want to achieve above. For this, how about this answer?

In this answer, I used TextFinder for achieving your goal.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Compras');

  // I modified below script.
  sheet
    .getRange(1, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1)
    .createTextFinder("1")
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .forEach(e => sheet.hideColumn(e));
}
```

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [hideColumn(column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn)